# C++ - Overloading stream operators without cin or cout

Tags: c++, io, stream, operator-overloading

My task is to overload operators << and >> in Stack class, such that they can add or extract element from Stack. Example:

```
stack << 1 << 2 << 3;
stack >> a >> b >> c;     // a==3, b==2, c==1
```

I tried to do the task this way, but the solution seems to be incorrect:

```
std::ostream & operator<<(Stack lstack, const double &value)
{
  lstack.push(value);
  return lstack;
}
```

Could anyone give me some hints for that?

**EDIT:**

Okay, so I don't believe that I made such a silly mistake with that return type. Yet still, my program cannot compile after some changes. Here are the code snippets:

```
int main()
{
   Stack stos;
   std::cout << "***STACK***" << std::endl;
   stos.push(2); stos.push(5); stos.push(3);
   stos << 7;
   ...
}

//Stack.h
 #pragma once
 #include <iostream>
 class Stack
 {
   public:
    Stack();
    Stack(const Stack &);
   ~Stack();

    struct Element;
    virtual void push(double);
    virtual double  pop();
    virtual int empty();
    int sizeIt();
    int sizeRec();
    int countRec(Element*);

    Stack& operator=(const Stack&);
    Stack& operator<<(Stack&, const double);

  protected:
   struct Element
   {
      double value;
      Element *prev;
   };
   Element *top;
};   

//stack.cpp
   Stack& operator<<(Stack& lstack, const double value)
   {
     lstack.push(value);
     return lstack;
   }

   void Stack::push(double e)   
   {
      Element *newElem = new Element;
      newElem->value = e;
      newElem->prev = top;
      top = newElem;
   }
```

Right now, in the header file, my error is E0344: "too many parameters for this operator function" and in main C2679: 'Cannot found the operator, which takes right-side operand of type "int"'.

Comment: Why do you think the solution "seems to be incorrect"? What is the problem?

Comment: Seems to be incorrect, as in it doesn't even build? Your task is to understand the concepts behind how the overload works. What the return and input parameter types mean. Do you think us doing it for you is going to teach you something?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit : Good point. Coolerini - can you post your full code - ie. the usage which you think indicates incorrectness ?

Comment: This will not compile.

Comment: @amritanshu: [That is not necessarily true](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/07517b0651917cf9).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Nice, too... My variant would have been letting Stack inherit from ostream.

Comment: @Aconcagua: Mmm that's probably better actually 

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit nice but it could mislead OP too :)

Comment: I have edited the post. Sorry for the way I asked the question and, probably, for my code - I'm just the beginner.

Comment: *"too many parameters for this operator function"* This is because of your operator being a member function... Either have it as member, then leave the `Stack` parameter (it is the implicit `this`!) or make it a free function.

Comment: Actually, you have both, the free one (`Stack& operator<<(...)`) and the member one (declared only; implementation would have to look like `Stack& Stack::operator<<(double)`, if implemented outside class. Free one won't be found outside stack.cpp as not declared in header.

Comment: Thank you! It worked, when I implemented it using 'this' and leaving operator as a member function. I will do my best to improve the way of asking the questions in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems:

- Your code takes a *copy* of the `Stack`, breaking nesting
- Your code tries to return an `ostream&` as if it were a `Stack`, breaking compilation (well, maybe; you didn't deem us worthy of seeing its definition)

I'd guess you meant to write the following:

```
Stack& operator<<(Stack& lstack, const double value)
{
    lstack.push(value);
    return lstack;
}
```